# How to make marquee text cut at a certain point and come from the other side again?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I created a musicplayer UI and want to make it responsive. When the song title is too long I want it to be an marquee text scrolling from the leading of the `VStack` to trailing side. Once the text reached the trailing side it should cut and appear from the leading side again. Currently it just goes outside of the `VStack` and then starts the animation over again.
[image]

This is my code:

```
@State var scrollText = false
VStack(alignment: .leading) {
  VStack {
     Text(album.songs.title ?? "").font(.system(size: 13))
     .foregroundColor(Color.white).fixedSize()
     .offset(x: scrollText ? 40 : 0)
     .animation(Animation.linear(duration: 4)
     .repeatForever(autoreverses: false))
     .onAppear() {
                   scrollText.toggle()
                 }
        }.frame(width: 100, height: 18, alignment: .leading)
         .background(.red)
    Text(album.name).font(.system(size: 9)).foregroundColor(Color.gray)
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it:

```
struct MarqueeText: View {
    @State var text: String
    @State var storedSize: CGSize = .zero
    @State var offset: CGFloat = 30
    var font: UIFont
    var animationSpeed: Double = 0.04
    var delayTime: Double = 0
    
    func textSize() -> CGSize {
        let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font]
        let size = (text as NSString).size(withAttributes: attributes)
        return size
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false){
            Text(text)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .font(Font(font))
                .offset(x: offset)
                .padding(.horizontal, 15)
        }
        .disabled(true)
        .onAppear() {
            let baseText = text
            (1...10).forEach { _ in
                storedSize = textSize()
                text.append(" ")
            }
            text.append(baseText)
            storedSize = textSize()
            let timing: Double = (animationSpeed * storedSize.width)
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delayTime) {
                
                withAnimation(.linear(duration: timing)) {
                    offset = -storedSize.width
                }
            }
        }
        .onReceive(Timer.publish(every: (animationSpeed * storedSize.width) + delayTime, on: .main, in: .default).autoconnect()) { _ in
            offset = -15
            withAnimation(.linear(duration: (animationSpeed * storedSize.width))) {
                offset = -storedSize.width + 20
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my ContentView I check for the length of the text

```
func textSize(font: UIFont, text: String) -> CGSize {
        let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font]
        let size = (text as NSString).size(withAttributes: attributes)
        return size
    }

if 
textSize(font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13, weight: .bold), text: song.title).width 
>= 66 { // i check this value by just printing the result of the function
     MarqueeText(text: song.title, font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 13))
} else { 
Text(song.title)
.font(.system(size: 13)).foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                }
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason it goes outside of `VStack` because you set a const which is `40` to `.offset`. What you should `.offset` here is variable = width of cell - text.size.width ( depends on size of width text inside)

Code will be like this

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var scrollText = false
    @State var sizeOfText: CGSize = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
          VStack {
              Text("abc").font(.system(size: 13))
             .foregroundColor(Color.white).fixedSize()
             .background(GeometryReader { (geometryProxy : GeometryProxy) in
                             HStack {}
                             .onAppear {
                                 sizeOfText = geometryProxy.size
                             }
                         })
             .offset(x: scrollText ? 100 - sizeOfText.width : 0)
             .animation(Animation.linear(duration: 4)
             .repeatForever(autoreverses: false))
             .onAppear() {
                scrollText.toggle()
             }
        }.frame(width: 100, height: 18, alignment: .leading)
        .background(.red)
        Text("album.net").font(.system(size: 9)).foregroundColor(Color.gray)
        }
    }
}
```

The result:
[image: Result]